# Dwarf Fortress industry dependencies

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm looking for an industry dependency map. I seem to remember seeing one at some point, but I can't find it again.

Something that shows, for example, seeds are required for farms, which produce plants, which are needed for brewing and cooking and tailoring...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This flowchart](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/File:DFflowchart.png) from the DF wiki shows all workshops, their inputs, and their outputs.

Comment: Great, I couldn't find that!!!

Comment: I just happened to find it while researching a different question.

Comment: Magmawiki is dead, long live https://dwarffortresswiki.org/ ! That said, maybe this will help: https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/From_Caravan_to_Happy_Dwarves

Answer (score 6):

All of this information can be viewed on the [Industries wiki page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Industry), broken out by industry.

Comment: +1, but I'd copy at least some relevant information here to help with Google indexing

Comment: @C. Ross: I remember seeing an actual diagram somewhere, though it may have not been for the current version.

Comment: @antony I'll poke around some more when I have time.  I'd like to find one myself.

Comment: http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Glass_industry#Glass_Industry_Flowchart is what I was remembering I think. I wish there was one that included all industries.

Comment: @antony It'd be a cursed busy flow chart.